# FluentAssertions causing ObjectDisposedException when ExcludingNestedObjects is set

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have an EF model defined as follows:

```
public class ProgramManagerRolePermission
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid ShardKey { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public Guid PermissionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
    public virtual ProgramManagerRole Role { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PermissionId))]
    public virtual ProgramManagerPermission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

I've got the following test code:

```
using (var repo = IdentityProgramRepositoryFactory.Get())
{
    var role = repo.ProgramManagerRoles
        .Include(r => r.Permissions)
        .SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == roleId);
    role.Permissions.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] {
        new Repo.ProgramManagerRolePermission
        {
            PermissionId = ProgramManagerPermissions.GrantOrRevokeRoles.Id,
            RoleId = roleId,
            ShardKey = identityProgramId
        },
        new Repo.ProgramManagerRolePermission
        {
            PermissionId = ProgramManagerPermissions.ManageNode.Id,
            RoleId = roleId,
            ShardKey = identityProgramId
        }
    }, options => options.ExcludingNestedObjects());
}
```

When I run it the test fails because an `ObjectDisposedException` is thrown with the message:

> Safe handle has been closed

If I change the last line to:

```
}, options => options.Excluding(p => p.Role).Excluding(p => p.Permission));
```

Then the test runs successfully.

The only two nested objects are `Role` and `Permission`. When I exclude them explicitly the test works, when I tell it to exclude all nested objects it appears to still be trying to navigate through them.

Anyone run into this before? Any explanation as to why what I think should be happening isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ExcludingNestedObjects`, which means it will not do a structural comparison between the objects exposed by the `Role` and `Permission` objects. Those are properties of your root object. But it will still try to do a simple equality check.

Comment: I misinterpreted what the intellisense was telling me for `ExcludingNestedObjects`. I incorrectly interpreted it as essentially meaning it would completely skip any property that was a reference type. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Well, I can see that you could misinterpret this.